# How to store the correct datetime with my timezone with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

When i store the data from my API with postman(Management store with sequelize). The date is wrong. 
here the result 
[image]

it should be like this

[image]

i've been try to using `dialectOptions {dateStrings : true, typeCast: true}` but the type of data is return String not Date.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

try something like this and change the json variable to your own date from json:

```
var json = "\"2020-03-14T15:32:42.782Z\"";

var dateStr = JSON.parse(json);  

var date = new Date(dateStr);
console.log(date);

const d = new Date(dateStr)
const ye = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(d)
const mo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: '2-digit' }).format(d)
const da = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(d)
const ho = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { hour: '2-digit', hour12: false }).format(d)
const min = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { minute: '2-digit' }).format(d)
const sec = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { second: '2-digit' }).format(d)

console.log(`${ye}-${mo}-${da} ${ho}:${min}:${sec}`)
```

the output will look like this:

```
2020-03-14 16:32:42
```

I hope I could help you like this..